# Are there tools to find out if a function exists in another one's call hierarchy?

Tags: c++, ide

While coding in C++ I find myself asking "does function X ever get called with function Y in the call stack?" Usually I'm trying to find some kind of scoper or mutex that function Y holds.

I usually answer this question by expanding everything in my IDE's Find Call Hierarchy function to try and find a link, but I work in a large enough code base that this can become very time consuming.

Does anyone know of a way to quickly figure this out? It seems like if you could just get a call hierarchy of a function as raw text you could quickly grep through for any other function, but I haven't been able to find a feature in any of the mainstream sources of call hierarchies that could output this.

I work on enough platforms that any answer would be helpful, but bonus points if it's attainable via something popular like XCode, VS or CScope.